# Equation of a circle with two points and tangent to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Two given points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2). Also there is a given circle (center,radius). The question is finding the equation of circle that passes two points and tangent to a given circle. It is known that there are two solutions. I am writing a computer code to draw this circle, therefore I need an equations that give me the center and radius of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing in parametric form the equation of the perpendicular bisector of $A_1$ and $A_2$. Call $P(t)$ a generic point on that bisector. Call $O$ the center of the given circle and $R$ its radius. Then I would impose
$$
|OP|-R=|A_1P|.
$$
This gives you a second degree equation for $t$, with two solutions corresponding to the two circles you need.